# Add functions to already declared class

Tags: php, class, http, sockets

Assume the following class structure in file A (which could contain, for example, socket functions):

**File A:**

```
class http{
  public function __construct(){
    
    echo "Handle sockets here!";
  }
}
```

And this other class in **file B** which could contain HTTP handshake functions:

```
class http{
  public function http_handhsake(){
    
    echo "Handle http handshake here!";
  }
}
```

And I would like to call my functions like this:

```
include "file_a.php";
$http = new http("0.0.0.0", 8080);

$http->http_handshake();
```

How do you merge the two classes if they are in different files? Is there a better way to structure my code?

Comment: PHP doesn't really support splitting a class definition across multiple files. Why do you have to do it this way?

Comment: @Barmar to better organise my code. So like, my first file would handle socket connections and threading, and the other file would handle http tasks, another file would handle websockets.. etc. How would you organise your code?

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn how to use mixins and multiple inheritance.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the headsups. can you link me a good ressource, or is everything on PHP.net?

Comment: Google "php multiple inheritance" and you'll find tutorials.